# How to position pixels to the right

Tags: css

Look at following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hqn4gLk6/

```
<div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:5px">
        <button type=button id="fdfdd"  class="btn btn-small" style="width:150px;">sadfasfdsfdfd</button>
    </div>
```

I want the button to be positioned 5 px from the right side of the page.

I tried using margin-right witch was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could position your element `absolute` and then use the css `right` like:

```
<div style="display:inline-block; position:absolute; right:5px;">
    <button type=button id="fdfdd"  class="btn btn-small" style="width:150px;">sadfasfdsfdfd</button>
</div>
```

also look at your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqn4gLk6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

```
<div style="margin-left:@marginDate;">
    <h2 style="display:inline-block;">454544555 </h2><p style="margin-left:10px;display:inline-block"> sadfasfsafsdf</p>



      /*added float:right; to the style only and some margin */

<div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:5px; float:right;">

/* done working */

                <button type=button id="schema"  class="btn btn-small" style="width:150px;">sadfasfdsfdfd</button>
            </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: also if you want the button to be in line with other objects you can just add to the button or the div in button some margin top example

Answer (score 0):

I used floats to get what you asked for. I updated your [js.fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hqn4gLk6/3/) if you want to see it in action.

```
<div style="clear:both">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <h2 style="display:inline-block;">454544555 </h2>
        <p style="margin-left:10px;display:inline-block"> sadfasfsafsdf</p>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; margin-right:5px">
           <button type=button id="schema"  class="btn btn-small" style="width:150px;">sadfasfdsfdfd</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```